# Resharper 9 File Layout: defining sort order when sorting by access modifier not possible?

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-9.0

after installing R# 9.0 my custom file layout from 8.2 did not work anymore.
I recreated the same pattern using the layout designer which is new in 9.0.

The part I could not reproduce was the detailed ordering definition for properties using access modifiers:

Pre-9.0 it looked like this:

```
[...]
<Sort>
    <Access Order="private public internal protected-internal protected"/>
</Sort>
[...]
```

... resulting in the properties being ordered as defined - especially: `private` first!

In 9.0 when using the new Designer the produced XAML is the following:

```
[...]
<Entry.SortBy>
    <Access />
</Entry.SortBy>
[...]
```

... which still sorts the members by their access modifier *but using some default ordering spec*. The designer does not allow for specifying any additional attributes and editing the XAML manually as in pre-9.0 produces errors.

**Is there any way in R# 9.0 to control the order of `public`, `private` etc members like this?**

<strike>Btw. the same issue exists for other sort specs like `Kind`: it is not possible anymore to specify that e.g. `property` should go before `method` etc.</strike>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out the ordering can still be specified as in pre-9.0 - but with slightly different syntax:

```
[...]
<Entry.SortBy>
    <Access Order="private public internal protectedinternal protected"/>
</Entry.SortBy>
[...]
```

The difference was that `protected-internal` now has to be `protectedinternal` instead...

Also be aware that you have to do this manually in the XAML view since the visual layout designer does not support this setting yet. **(But it will detect errors in your edits - so be sure to switch back and forth from XAML to Designer view to check if you broke anything).**

For the second part regarding kinds: they can be sorted, too. This was a oversight of mine.

**Edit:**
A whole entry then looks like this:

```
<Entry DisplayName="non-private Fields">
  <Entry.Match>
    <And>
      <Kind Is="Field" />
      <Not>
        <Access Is="Private" />
      </Not>
    </And>
  </Entry.Match>
  <Entry.SortBy>
    <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
    <Name Is="Enter Pattern Here" />
  </Entry.SortBy>
</Entry>
```

Comment: Could you share your xaml?  I'm having a hard time getting this to work.

Comment: @RobertChrist: I edited my answer as i could not get a code block to show correctly within the comment section. HTH