# Resharper: Set sort order for class/method modifiers 'static'/'sealed' vS 'public'/'internal'/'protected'

Tags: sorting, configuration, resharper, modifiers

When it comes to 'static' and 'sealed' I would like the default sort order for my classes (and methods) to be like this:

```
         sealed public class Foo {   static public void Bar() {}  }
```

The default settings of Resharper automatically reorder the above class definition to:

```
         public sealed class Foo {    public static void Bar() {} }
```

How can one change the default sort order for 'static'/'sealed' vS 'public'/'private' etc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802756/resharper-9-file-layout-defining-sort-order-when-sorting-by-access-modifier-not somewhat relevant but still not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I somehow managed to miss the option:

Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style -> Modifiers -> Modifiers Order